# Regex needed for password

Tags: regex

I require a regex for password field

I tried before posting but couldn't get through.

which validates the field for:

- at least one special char
- at least one alphabetic character
- at least one numeric char?

Comment: You should try before asking here, FYI.

Comment: If you're going to go down this route, I'd suggest using a decent password strength checker rather than a basic regex as described -- see http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/ for a few pre-built scripts you can download.

Comment: check out this article: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t604909-regularexpression-validation-for-password-in-asp-net.html Hope this helps!

Comment: [Password Validation Via Regular Expression](http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/)

Comment: who has voted me down at last moment as the question asked very long back ? Any way to make this votes goes up?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an article on how to write regex password validation strings:

http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/

In your case, you would look for something like this:

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[.,!-@#$%^&+=_]).*$
```

This would require your password to be at least eight characters, contain a letter, a number, and a special character (one of these: **.,!-@#$%^&+=_**)

If you are really struggling with regex, I would suggest you try something like this (free) tool for helping you build regex expressions:

http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: I'd add the usual `.,!-` too, and move that 8 char requirement out of the lookahead, something like: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[-.,-+!=_?@#$%^&=]).{8,}\z`

Comment: @Qtax - thanks, I updated my regex to have those characters as well.  Out of curiosity, why would you move the 8-character requirement out of the lookahead?

Comment: because it's slower having it in one if you are still doing `.*` after, and that first `.*` will cause the regex to backtrack, remove it, not needed. The anchors are not really needed either, but the `^` makes it fail faster. (Also it gets shorter (: )

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that will require at least one alpha, one numeric, and one special character.

```
^.*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W])(?=.*[\d]).*$
```

[More info here.](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/)